# Skeleton of a Multi-threaded web crawler in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to prototype a simple structure for a Web crawler in Java. Until now the prototype is just trying to do the below:

- Initialize a Queue with list of starting URLs
- Take out a URL from Queue and submit to a new Thread
- Do some work and then add that URL to a Set of already visited URLs

For the Queue of starting URLs, I am using a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for synchronizing.

For Set of already visited URLs, I am using `Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<URL>())`

To spawn new Threads I am using `ExecutorService`.

**Please review if the design is optimized and if multi-threading is implemented correctly here.**

In the block of code in `CrawlerTask`:

```
synchronized (crawler) {
                if (!crawler.getUrlVisited().contains(url)) {
                    new Scraper().scrape(url);
                    crawler.addURLToVisited(url);
                }
            }
```

I think that the lock on `crawler` object will let only 1 Thread proceed at a time (since the object is passed to every `Callable`), which does not confirm with the multi-threaded design here.

Starting class for the application:

```
public class CrawlerApp {

    private static Crawler crawler;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        crawler = new Crawler();
        initializeApp();
        startCrawling();
    }

    private static void startCrawling() {
        WorkerManager workers = WorkerManager.getInstance();
        while (!crawler.getUrlHorizon().isEmpty()) {
            URL url = crawler.getUrlHorizon().poll();
            if(!crawler.getUrlVisited().contains(url)){
                Future future = workers.getExecutor().submit(new CrawlerTask(url, crawler));
            }

        }

        try {
            workers.getExecutor().shutdown();
            workers.getExecutor().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void initializeApp() {

        Properties config = new Properties();
        try {
            config.load(CrawlerApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("url-horizon.properties"));
            String[] horizon = config.getProperty("urls").split(",");
            for (String link : horizon) {
                URL url = new URL();
                url.setURL(link);
                crawler.getUrlHorizon().add(url);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

`Crawler.java` which maintains the Queue of URLs and Set of already visited URLs.

```
public class Crawler {

    private volatile ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URL> urlHorizon = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URL>();

    public void setUrlHorizon(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URL> urlHorizon) {
        this.urlHorizon = urlHorizon;
    }

    public ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URL> getUrlHorizon() {
        return urlHorizon;
    }

    private volatile Set<URL> urlVisited = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<URL>());

    public void setUrlVisited(Set<URL> urlVisited) {
        this.urlVisited = urlVisited;
    }

    public Set<URL> getUrlVisited() {
        return urlVisited;
    }

    public void addURLToVisited(URL url) {
        if (getUrlVisited().contains(url)) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate found in already visited:" + url.getURL());
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Adding to visited set:" + url.getURL());
            getUrlVisited().add(url);
        }
    }

}
```

`URL.java` is just a class with `private String url` and overriden `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Also, `Scraper.scrape()` just has dummy implementation until now:

```
public void scrape(URL url){
        System.out.println("Done scrapping:"+url.getURL());
    }
```

`WorkerManager` to create Threads:

```
public class WorkerManager {
    private static final Integer WORKER_LIMIT = 10;
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(WORKER_LIMIT);

    public ExecutorService getExecutor() {
        return executor;
    }

    private static volatile WorkerManager instance = null;

    private WorkerManager() {
    }

    public static WorkerManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (WorkerManager.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new WorkerManager();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public Future createWorker(Callable call) {
        return executor.submit(call);
    }

}
```

`CrawlerTask` which is run in a separate Thread for every URL:

```
public class CrawlerTask implements Callable {
    public CrawlerTask(URL url, Crawler crawler) {
        this.url = url;
        this.crawler = crawler;
    }

    URL url;
    Crawler crawler;

    private void crawlTask() {
        synchronized (crawler) {
            if (!crawler.getUrlVisited().contains(url)) {
                new Scraper().scrape(url);
                crawler.addURLToVisited(url);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        crawlTask();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Take look into ExecutorService. It contains: a queue of task and a set of workers. So, crawlers should be the workers of that design and they should add tasks (urls) to that queue.

Comment: @rdllopes can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your  urlHorizon (ConcurrentLinkedQueue) is unneeded. There is already a task queue inside your executorService.  Just add new tasks to your executorService and the workers will receive them. I am preparing a more elaborated review but you can start working with those ideas.

Comment: Fork and Join would be a better approaching.

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @h.j.k. No I am not

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify your solution a little bit. Some classes are unnecessary.

### Sugestion for CrawlerApp

```
private static final Integer WORKER_LIMIT = 10;

private static final BlockingQueue queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
 // number of active threads...
private static final AtomicInteger NUMBER_ACTIVE_THREADS= new AtomicInteger(0);

private final static ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(WORKER_LIMIT, WORKER_LIMIT, 0L,
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);

private static Crawler crawler;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    crawler = new Crawler();
    initializeApp();
    startCrawling();
}

private static void startCrawling() throws InterruptedException {
    while (ATOMIC_INTEGER.intValue() > 0 || !queue.isEmpty()){
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

}

private static void initializeApp() {

    Properties config = new Properties();
    try {
        config.load(CrawlerApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("url-horizon.properties"));
        String[] horizon = config.getProperty("urls").split(",");
        for (String link : horizon) {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            executor.submit(new CrawlerTask(url, crawler, executor, NUMBER_ACTIVE_THREADS)); // don't forget to increase/decrease atomic_integer.
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

There is a huge contention problem in CrawlerTask. Reduce the synchronized area.
Better visit twice a page than **block all the execution**.

### CrawlerTask

```
    private void crawlTask() {
    if (crawler.getUrlVisited().contains(url)){
        return ;
    }
    new Scraper().scrape(url);
    crawler.addURLToVisited(url);
}
```

Comment: as per your design of using `LinkedBlockingQueue`, what is the use of using `Thread.sleep(100)`? Since the threads will wait if the queue is empty.

Comment: I am assuming that each task consist of fetching, parsing a URL and adding outgoing links to queues.  NOTE: It should be done using submit method of the executor. Since we don't know when it will be completed, there should be a loop verifying when it happen. It just verify and sleep a small portion of time (100 milliseconds).